# Trying to use if and Else if to select a template based on a google sheet cell response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm new to Google Apps Script and I've created a Google Form that when an input in one of the cells changes, a different template is used and populated, then emailed. I created a similar Google Form with only one template and would appreciate any help as it's currently not working. Here's the code that I have so far:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var applicationDate = e.values[1];
  var customerName = e.values[2];
  var occupation = e.values[3];
  var teamMember = e.values[4];
  var tmCell = e.values[5];
  var address = e.values[6];
  var city = e.values[7];
  var postcode = e.values[8];
  var tmEmail = e.values[9];


  if (occupation = 'option1') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  };
  else if (occupation = 'option 2') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  };
  else if (occupation = 'option 3') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  };
  else if (occupation = 'option 4') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  };
  else if (occupation = 'option 5') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  };
  else(occupation = 'option 6') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  };


  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder ID removed')
  var copy = file.makeCopy('Client Recommendation' + ',' + ' ' + customerName +
    ',' + ' ' + applicationDate, folder);

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText('{{date}}', applicationDate);
  body.replaceText('{{customerName}}', customerName);
  body.replaceText('{{occupation}}', occupation);
  body.replaceText('{{teamMember}}', teamMember);
  body.replaceText('{{tmCell}}', tmCell);
  body.replaceText('{{address}}', address);
  body.replaceText('{{city}}', city);
  body.replaceText('{{postcode}}', postcode);
  body.replaceText('{{tmEmail}}', tmEmail);

  doc.saveAndClose();

  var pdffolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("drive ID removed");
  var pdfFILE = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
  pdfFILE.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
  var theFolder = pdffolder;
  var theFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfFILE);
  theFolder.addFile(theFile);

  var pdfEMAIL = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf')
    .getBytes();
  var message = "Here's the client recommendations for " + customerName + " " +
    ".\nMany Thanks!\nGo Oilers!";
  var emailTo = tmEmail; // Team Members email
  var subject = "Client Recommendations, " + customerName + ", " +
    applicationDate;
  var attach = {
    fileName: "Client Recommendations " + customerName + '.pdf',
    content: pdfEMAIL,
    mimeType: 'application/pdf'
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {
    attachments: [attach]
  }); //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to running the script. You only need to modify the `if` block to conform with the [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). The end result must look similar to this:

```js
if (occupation = 'option1') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  } else if (occupation = 'option 2') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  } else if (occupation = 'option 3') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  } else if (occupation = 'option 4') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  } else if (occupation = 'option 5') {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  } else {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID removed')
  }
```

Please take notice how the *option 6* check has been deleted. If this causes problematic behaviour in your scenario, please substitute it with another `else if` section.

Additionally, I strongly recommend you to opt for a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement instead of an `if` one. `switch` will first evaluate the `occupation` variable and then execute the statement associated by its value. Please, don't hesitate to ask me any doubts.

---

### UPDATE

In your new comment I can see that the switch is made similar to this:

```js
switch (file) {
  case occupation = ("option 1"):
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('Template ID') break;
  case occupation = ("option 2"):
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID') break;
}
```

I understand that you want to evaluate `file` (line 2) and then branch based on `occupation`. In that case `occupation` should be evaluated directly like this:

```
switch (occupation) {
  case "option 1":
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('Template ID') break;
  case "option 2":
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID') break;
}
```

Feel free to comment back for any questions.

New Updated Code, still with a 100% trigger error:
This is the error message (Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.)

```
function myRecommendation(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var applicationDate = e.values[1];
  var customerName = e.values[2];
  var occupation = e.values[3];
  var teamMember = e.values[4];
  var tmCell = e.values[5];
  var address = e.values[6];
  var city = e.values[7];
  var postcode = e.values[8];
  var tmEmail = e.values[9];


  switch (occupation) {
    case "option 1":
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID Removed')
      break;
    case "option 2":
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID Removed')
      break;
    case "option 3":
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID Removed')
      break;
    case "option 4":
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID Removed')
      break;
    case "option 5":
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID Removed')
      break;
    case "option 6":
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID Removed')
      break;    
};
  
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID Removed')
  var copy = file.makeCopy('Client Recommendation' + ',' + ' ' + customerName +
    ',' + ' ' + applicationDate, folder);

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText('{{date}}', applicationDate);
  body.replaceText('{{customerName}}', customerName);
  body.replaceText('{{occupation}}', occupation);
  body.replaceText('{{teamMember}}', teamMember);
  body.replaceText('{{tmCell}}', tmCell);
  body.replaceText('{{address}}', address);
  body.replaceText('{{city}}', city);
  body.replaceText('{{postcode}}', postcode);
  body.replaceText('{{tmEmail}}', tmEmail);

  doc.saveAndClose();

  var pdffolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID Removed");
  var pdfFILE = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
  pdfFILE.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
  var theFolder = pdffolder;
  var theFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfFILE);
  theFolder.addFile(theFile);

  var pdfEMAIL = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf')
    .getBytes();
  var message = "Here's the client recommendations for " + customerName + " " +
    ".\nMany Thanks!\nGo Oilers!";
  var emailTo = tmEmail; // Team Members email
  var subject = "Client Recommendations, " + customerName + ", " +
    applicationDate;
  var attach = {
    fileName: "Client Recommendations " + customerName + '.pdf',
    content: pdfEMAIL,
    mimeType: 'application/pdf'
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {
    attachments: [attach]
  }); //
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and advice. I made te changes that you mentioned and this message  TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
    at myFunction(Code:3:21) . Are you able to find what I'm doing wrong? Also I will look at making your recommendation to change to a switch statement rather than a if one

Comment: Hi there @JonHolland! That alert warns you about accessing undefined variables. I assume that it is related to the `e` variable at the beginning of the function. Normally that variable refers to an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that would be created on trigger firing. In case of running the code manually (as opposed from a trigger) the event object won't be created and you will see that alert.

Comment: Thanks @jacques I tried to update the code with Switch statement instead of the if and else if but it didn't work. Here's my code any help would be greatly appreciated.    switch(file) {case  occupation = ("option 1"):     var file = DriveApp.getFileById('Template ID')
    break;
    case occupation = ("option 2"):
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('template ID')
    break; }

Comment: @JonHolland check out my new updated answer and let me know any doubts.

Comment: thank you for your update. I'm not sure why but I'm getting a 100% error rate on the On form submit trigger.

Comment: @JonHolland To better analyze that situation, could you please share your final code and its error messages? For a more legible and extense script, include it in the original question instead of a new comment.

Comment: Jacques-Guzel Heron I've added the code, any help would be greatly appreciated @Jacques-Guzel Heron

Comment: @JonHolland That error message warns about the method [`DriveApp.getFolderById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid). To discard expected errors, please make sure that it has the correct ID and you have the permissions to access that folder. Since the script uses that method more than once, please check them one by one by commenting out the rest. If you keep facing any error, please come back and share your findings.